# Index of Summation Shift? Power Series and Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series

I have never had to index shift a summation series before, and it seems relatively straightforward, however, I am looking at an example in my textbook that doesn't make sense.  I am wondering if someone might be able to outline the steps that appear to be missing.

Apologies for the formatting issue; perhaps someone can help with that?

Here is how it appears in the textbook:

$(1+2x^2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} + 6x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$

$= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[2n(n-1)+6n+2]a_{n}x^n$

So it looks as though the two rightmost terms were combined somehow, but I cannot figure how this took place.

Can someone help with my understanding?  I've never done anything like this before, and I'm frustrated I can't understand the rest of the example because of this.

Thanks!

Comment: So I think I've made some progress in terms of figuring out what was done.  It looks as though the exponents of the terms were reduced to x^n, and that this had the effect of changing the start of the index to zero.  It's hard to explain.  Does anyone know what I mean?

Comment: Yep. I think I know what you mean, the lumping in the $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms is a bit slippery.

Comment: See my reply below.  The only thing I had to go off of was my intuition and the text.  So I had to make some conclusions.  Check out the screenshot from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just distribute to see:
\begin{align}
&(1+2x^2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} + 6x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n  =\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} +2x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2}+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}6na_{n}xx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_{n}x^n \\ 
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^2x^{n-2}+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}6na_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_{n}x^n \\ 
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n}+
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}6na_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2a_{n}x^n +6a_1x+2a_0+2a_1x \\ 
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( 2n(n-1)+
6n+2 \right)a_nx^n +8a_1x+2a_0\\ 
\end{align}
Now, notice the rightmost sum begins at $n=0$ in your post, can we see the exceptional terms as the $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms in the text's expression?

Added: I thought it might be useful to show how to group all the terms: continuing,
\begin{align}
&(1+2x^2)\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} + 6x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n  =\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a{_{n}}x^{n-2} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 2n(n-1)+
6n+2 \right)a_nx^n \\ 
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+2)(j+1)a{_{j+2}}x^{j} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 2n(n-1)+
6n+2 \right)a_nx^n \\ 
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j+2)(j+1)a{_{j+2}}x^{j} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( 2n(n-1)+
6n+2 \right)a_nx^n \\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( [2n(n-1)+
6n+2]a_n+(n+2)(n+1)a{_{n+2}} \right)x^n 
\end{align}
So, then when we have this is zero we find relations between the $n$-th and $n+2$-th coefficients.

Comment: to answer my question: yes, yes we can.

Comment: James, thanks for the reply.  Here is a screenshot of the lines in question from the example.  The index shows as zero.  Unless it's some sort of a mistake: http://imgur.com/c8FAx1b

Comment: no it's not a mistake. The $n=1$ gives $[2(1)(0)+6(1)+2]a_1x=8a_1x$ and $n=0$ gives $[2(0)(-1)+6(0)+2]a_0=2a_0$ so those exceptional terms get put into the right sum by starting $n$ at $0$ rather than $2$.

Comment: So it looks like the author just skipped over writing that out?

Comment: Yep. Think of it as the author sweeping the dirt into two piles rather than leaving 4.

Comment: Honestly, what you need to do to solve things later is to make one summation which gathers all terms as possible at each order, so, the thing were looking at is just a step towards that eventuality.

Comment: I think I see it now.  Basically, the first couple of terms for those two sums anyway will be zero, so it's ok to start them at zero.  Right?

Comment: Exactly, sadly the stack exchange software is now scolding us for discussion of math here. I hope the added few lines are helpful as you study further...